# Duplicates in String -Java 8 lambdas

Tags: java, string, lambda, java-8

I am trying to write a program to print duplicates and count in String using Java 8 lambdas, But getting this error while trying to insert the value into Map From List. Can someone please help with what's wrong. I first converted the String to CharArray then added to list so that I can do internal iteration over the list and check if the value exists already in Map to store count and each Character

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class PrintDuplicateInString {

 public static void main(String[] a) {
   printDuplicate("TestJava");
 }

 private static String printDuplicate(String s) {
    List<char[]> stringList = null;
    if(s != null && s.length() > 0) {
      char[] duplicateStr = s.toCharArray();
      stringList = Arrays.asList(s.toCharArray());
      TreeMap<Character,Integer> trmap = new TreeMap<>();
      stringList.forEach(i -> (trmap.containsKey(i))?(trmap.put(i,trmap.get(i)+1)):(trmap.put(i,1)));
    }
    stringList.forEach(System.out::println);
 }

}
```

Comment: Instead of linking to a picture of code, you should create a code block and include it in the question.  It would also be helpful if you specified the error you were getting.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a `List<char[]>`, you can store the characters of the string as:

```
List<Character> characters = s.chars()
                .mapToObj(e -> (char) e)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

further finding the frequency of the characters is straight forward:

```
Map<Character, Long> trMap = characters.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c, Collectors.counting()));
```

in the representation, that you've written it, this would look like:

```
Map<Character, Long> trmap = new TreeMap<>();
for (Character c : characters) {
    if (trmap.containsKey(c)) {
        trmap.put(c, trmap.get(c) + 1);
    } else {
        trmap.put(c, 1L);
    }
}
```

Comment: But it’s recommended to replace this `if (trmap.containsKey(c)) { trmap.put(c, trmap.get(c) + 1); } else { trmap.put(c, 1L); }` with `trmap.merge(c, 1, Integer::sum);`. For your stream solution, the `List<Character>` is obsolete, as you can create the `Map<Character, Long>` in a single operation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues going on

1. `stringList` is a `List<char[]>` (list of array of chars), but you actually want a `List<Character>` (list of individual characters)
2. The expression `trmap.containsKey(i) ? trmap.put(i, trmap.get(i)+1) : trmap.put(i,1)` returns an integer value, but `.forEach` is not expecting a return type

To convert a `String` to a list of Characters, you need to do `List<Character> stringList = s.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(Collectors.toList());`

You can then use the longer `if/else` form to compute the counts:

```java
stringList.forEach(i -> {
  if (trmap.containsKey(i)) {
      trmap.put(i, trmap.get(i) + 1);
  } else {
     trmap.put(i, 1);
 }
});
```

If you want to use more streams, you can use the `Collections.toMap(..)` collector

```java
Map<Character,Integer> counts = s.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
.collect(Collectors.toMap(
   Function.identity(),
   c -> 1,
   (v1,v2) -> v1+v2
);
```

What the parameters of  `toMap` do are:

1. `Function.identity()` says use the current character in the stream as the key value
2. `c -> 1` says to map the character to the integer value `1`, and store it as the value in the map
3. `(v1,v2) -> v1+v2` Is the conflict resolution function.  So if we are processing the stream and come across a character key that is already in the map, run this function to compute the updated value to store in the map.  `v1` represents the current count in the map, `v2` represents the `1` that you mapped the character to in the second argument, so `v1+v2` will return the sum of those two numbers and store it in the map under the character.  This can be further abbreviated as `Integer::sum`